# Lag without previous value in R

Tags: r

I have a df with 6 columns. I want to find the delta based on the date and also group by first few columns.

```
df <- data.frame (col1  = c('A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2'),
                  col2 = c('B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3'),
                  col3 = c('C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3'),
                  col4 = c('D1','D2','D22','D4','D5','D6','D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7','D8','D9'),
                  col5 = c('1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021',
                           '1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022',
                           '1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022'),
                  col6 = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,100, 200, 300,400,500,600,60,60, 60)
                  
)
diff_na<-df%>%
  group_by(col1,col2,col3,col4) %>%
  mutate(diff = col6 - lag(col6, default = first(col6,default = 0), order_by = col5))
```

Expected output is :

```
df11 <- data.frame (col1  = c('A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2'),
                  col2 = c('B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3'),
                  col3 = c('C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3','C1','C2','C3'),
                  col4 = c('D1','D2','D22','D4','D5','D6','D1','D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7','D8','D9'),
                  col5 = c('1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021','1/01/2021',
                           '1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022',
                           '1/01/2022','1/01/2022','1/01/2022'),
                  col6 = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,100, 200, 300,400,500,600,60,60, 60),
                  dfiff =c(0,0,30,0,0,0,90,180,300,360,450,540,60,60,60)
                  
)
```

I am facing an issue if the value in the previous col4 is not there , then it does not subtract the value. I mean it should treat the missing value as 0. I tried giving first default as 0. But somehow the last three diff values are 0 instead of 60.
Please guide where I am going wrong.

Row 3 has value in Col4 as D22 which is not there for date 01/01/2022 so 30 should be there. similary row 13,14,15 does not have corresponding value for date 01/01/2021. So diff col should have 60 .

Thanks & Regards,
R

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The last values should be 60, I mean if there is no match then the same value coming on the latest date should be value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution without `group_map`. I hope this does what you want, at least it reproduces the output for your example data.

I assume you want to group only by the first two letters of `col4` so I split the column into `col4a` and `col4b` grouped by `col4a` and arranged by `col4b` and `col5`. It seems you want to use `0` as a default value in the lag only for the values in the second year and input `0` in the first year (except when you have multiple values in the first year)

Also the way your final data is ordered is not very intuitive.

```
df12 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    col4a = str_sub(col4, 1, 2),
    col4b = str_sub(col4, 3, 3)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2, col3, col4a) %>%
  arrange(col5, col4b) %>% 
  mutate(
    dfiff = col6 - lag(col6, default=NA), 
    dfiff = coalesce(dfiff, if_else(col5=="1/01/2021" & col4b=="", 0, col6))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(col5, col4a, col1, col3, col2) %>% 
  select(-col4a, -col4b)
```

I hope this helps, some other remarks:

I highly recommend not using strings as dates, especially when the date format is one in which alphabetical sorting does not correspond to the order of the dates (here it works accidentally because you always use "1/01" of each year, but you might get some other data and then your code would produce wrong output), you could use `strptime` with the format `"%m/%d/%Y"` to parse the dates from your column (assuming the one digit number is the month and the two digit number is the day).

Please try to describe better what you wish to accomplish, just a short paragraph is enough in most cases. The example input and output helps, thanks for posting it. But it takes way less time to answer your question if one has more context and does not need to reverse engineer the whole logic from input and output and more people will answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

From the extra details in the comments section, it seems that we need to use some conditional logic because of the special status of the initial date in the data frame. One way to handle this is to use `group_split` and `map`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  group_split(col1, col2, col3, col4) %>%
  map(~ if(nrow(.x) > 1) {
    mutate(.x, diff = c(0, diff(col6))) 
    } else {
     mutate(.x, diff = if(col5 == '1/01/2021') 0 else col6) 
    }) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  arrange(rn) %>%
  select(-rn)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 7
#>    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5       col6  diff
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A1    B1    C1    D1    1/01/2021    10     0
#>  2 A1    B2    C2    D2    1/01/2021    20     0
#>  3 A1    B3    C3    D22   1/01/2021    30     0
#>  4 A2    B1    C1    D4    1/01/2021    40     0
#>  5 A2    B2    C2    D5    1/01/2021    50     0
#>  6 A2    B3    C3    D6    1/01/2021    60     0
#>  7 A1    B1    C1    D1    1/01/2022   100    90
#>  8 A1    B2    C2    D2    1/01/2022   200   180
#>  9 A1    B3    C3    D3    1/01/2022   300   300
#> 10 A2    B1    C1    D4    1/01/2022   400   360
#> 11 A2    B2    C2    D5    1/01/2022   500   450
#> 12 A2    B3    C3    D6    1/01/2022   600   540
#> 13 A2    B1    C1    D7    1/01/2022    60    60
#> 14 A2    B2    C2    D8    1/01/2022    60    60
#> 15 A2    B3    C3    D9    1/01/2022    60    60
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan, But first six values in diff should be zero.

Comment: @RBan but if the first few values should be zero, why should the last few values be 60? For example, the very last row is the only member of its group, so if the first member of a group should have a diff of 0, why should that one be 60? Are you sure you should be grouping by col4?

Comment: yeah , I think it is complicated. As first few rows is my base . So if for 01/01/2021 some value in Col4 is not present for 01/01/2022 then same value should appear otherwise 0 . But for 01/01/2022 records, if for Col4 is not present in 01/01/2021 , then same value should appear.

Comment: @RBan see my update. I have just realised that the value for D22 is different from your expected output, but your expected output does not match with the logic you described (D22 is not the same as D2, so they will be in different groups)